# Why did wariness take article before it?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

[The source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/wary?q=Wary).
I don’t understand why **wariness**, abstract and uncountable, did take article “a” before it? [image: screen shot of the source]

> - there was **a** wariness in her tone.

Comment: It's an optional article. It would be grammatical with or without the "a".

Comment: I was taught that with uncountable abstract noun we can’t put article unless it turned to be specific rather than in general. @J.R.

Comment: It's a good question that deserves a better than I can write at the moment. Hard and fast guidelines for prepositions and articles are hard to define, and many of those rules are rife with exceptions. You've done a good job locating one of those.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo This is really a literary device. Although "wariness" is an abstract noun, by putting the article before it, the author is giving the sense that this is a *specific* and perhaps particularly notable wariness.

Comment: I agree with Canadian Yankee. This was written this way for style and to evince a specific or notable wariness.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - I might paraphrase it like this: "There was a [certain] wariness in her tone."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indefinite article can be used to refer to slight quality or tendency, something just beginning to show itself or showing itself only slightly, or to a quality which is difficult to name or pin down, either because it is a mixture of things or ephemeral in nature.

> There was an excitement in her voice.

She was not bubbling over with excitement, but a degree of excitement was present and detectable.

> There was a certain something in her voice, but I can't say just what it was.

Comment: I can't say exactly why, but ***an excitement*** here doesn't sit very well with me. Nnot compared to ***sharpness, softness, tenderness***, for example - all of which sound just fine to me with or without an article (and they also work with a different preposition in ***... to** her voice*).